# Bash: read one column from one file and divided by one column in current file

Tags: bash, awk

I want to use bash to read one column from one file and divided by one column in current file and replace the column.

for example, I have one file called input.txt

```
1 2 3
1 4 3
1 8 3
```

And I want to read second column of the file and divide with 3rd column of current file aim_file.txt:

```
1 1 4
3 4 8
8 8 16
```

So I got result.txt:

```
1 1 2
3 4 2
8 8 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$2; next} a[FNR]{$3 /= a[FNR]} 1' input.txt aim_file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
1 1 2
3 4 2
8 8 2
```

- We first iterate `input.txt` and store the 2nd column in an associative array by index of line#
- Next while iterating `aim_file.txt` we divide 3rd column with the value stored in array

Comment: Thank you for your efficient answer! Do you know, if I want to also multiply some constant number in column 3 how to do it?

Comment: that would be just: `awk {$3 *= 5} 1' file`